Issue with AWS S3 Integration in React App
I'm working on a React app where I've integrated an AWS S3 bucket for managing media using the AWS SDK. According to my hosting provider, everything is set up correctly, and the website is live. However, when I load the web app, I see a blank white page. In the console, I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: t is not a constructor
    at YX (index-BX6CUHDm.js:103:23845)
    at ye (index-BX6CUHDm.js:117:776)
    at index-BX6CUHDm.js:93:95623
    at index-BX6CUHDm.js:1:142
    at index-BX6CUHDm.js:377:138758

Has anyone faced a similar issue? How can I resolve this? Any suggestions for debugging or fixing this error?
I integrated an AWS S3 bucket into my React app using the AWS SDK to handle media storage. I followed the necessary steps to configure the S3 bucket and ensure proper connection between the app and the bucket. After deployment, I expected the media to load correctly from the S3 bucket, and for the app to display as usual without issues.
However, when I load the app, I encounter a blank white page. The browser console shows the error:
Uncaught TypeError: t is not a constructor
    at YX (index-BX6CUHDm.js:103:23845)
    at ye (index-BX6CUHDm.js:117:776)
    at index-BX6CUHDm.js:93:95623
    at index-BX6CUHDm.js:1:142
    at index-BX6CUHDm.js:377:138758

I was expecting the app to display correctly, but the issue seems related to an error in the JavaScript code.

If the issue is with the code then we need to see it to tell what's wrong with it. You can click on the lines in the error message to see what throws the error, even if it's minified you should be able to recognize what part of your code it is.
